# Make Radio buttons "pretty" with CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on an app that uses radio buttons. I'm trying to figure out how to make my radio buttons look better than the default radio buttons. However, I have not had any luck finding any examples online. Everything I find changes the radio buttons to a toggle button.

Basically, I want the radio button approach. I just want it to be bigger. I also want the selected radio button in a group to be green.

Is there a way to do this with CSS? If so, how? Or, do I need to use some custom control library?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/ visit this link and customize your code according the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prevalent method is to use `::before` pseudoelement, and format this. The radio/checkbox must be visually hidden.

```css
input[type="radio"].fancy {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: -12px;
}

input[type="radio"].fancy + label::before {
    content: "";
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

input[type="radio"].fancy:checked + label::before {
    content: "•";
    color: #777777;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

input[type="radio"].fancy:disabled + label::before {
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="radio" class="fancy" id="radio1" name="radiogroup1" />
  <label for="radio1">Fancy radio1</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" class="fancy" id="radio2" name="radiogroup1" />
  <label for="radio2">Fancy radio2</label>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="radio" class="fancy" id="radio3" name="radiogroup1" disabled="disabled" />
  <label for="radio3">Disabled radio</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "css customized radio buttons" yielded a lots of useful results, such as [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/), here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dghjLra2/) based on that tutorial, code provided below. Obviously, this is kind of workaround solution rather than native way of styling the radio buttons which to my knowledge doesn't exist.

HTML:

```
<div class="radio">  
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>  
    <label for="male">Male</label>  
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>  
    <label for="female">Female</label>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;  
    padding-left: 25px;  
    margin-right: 15px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
} 

input[type=radio] {  
    display: none;  
}  

label::before {  
    content: "";  
    display: inline-block;  

    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  

    margin-right: 10px;  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    bottombottom: 1px;  
    background-color: #aaa;  
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);  
} 

.radio label::before {  
    border-radius: 8px;  
} 

input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {  
    content: "\2022";  
    color: #f3f3f3;  
    font-size: 30px;  
    text-align: center;  
    line-height: 18px;  
}
```

Comment: There is no `:before` selector in the specification. Use `::before` instead.

Comment: @Dávid Horváth, thanks, corrected, I just copied over the code from the tutorial page without checking it as it was working just fine... FYI, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) states this: "Browsers also accept the notation :before introduced in CSS 2.", but yes, standard appears to be `::before`.

Comment: ... but `:before` really seems to be valid as well considering the [w3.org spec of CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#before-and-after).

Comment: :before is not valid, for this is CSS3 (see box-shadow etc.).

Comment: @Dávid Horváth, from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp): "CSS3 is completely backwards-compatible with earlier versions of CSS." <-- so if `:before` is valid in CSS2 then it is valid in CSS3 as well, end of story I guess..

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done with the help of background image, below code snippets can be helpful

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="radio" /> No
```

CSS :

```
 .radio {
  width: 19px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  background: url(radio.png) no-repeat;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}
```

links can help : 
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/